# ASP.NET Core WebAPI Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating an API using ASP.NET Core, and below is my controller code.

I have given the controller and Startup code below, along with fiddler request/response log. I am getting a 404 Not Found error. Please advise what am I missing?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string RegisterUser(User newUser)
    {
        // Code to register user in system
        return succecss/failure message

    }
}
```

I tried suggested attribute routing from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing but still no luck. I am not sure what I am missing.

Please note that with the Web API template , there is no default routing in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The following is my fiddler request:

```
URL: http://localhost:8011/api/User/RegisterUser

Verb= post

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8011
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 77

Request body
{"FirstName": "TEST FirstName", "LastName": "Test Last Name", "EmailId":"A@BB.COM","Password":"1"}

Output in response header:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[Route("api/[controller]")]` on the controller, together with a `[HttpPost]` on the action means that the action will be available at `/api/[controller]`. So in your case `/api/User`.

Unless you include `[action]` in the route template, the method name of the action will not be included in the route.

So, try a POST to `/api/User`, or change the route attribute on the controller to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`.

---

Note that the reason the API project template does not include default routes in the `Startup` is because with APIs you are expected to configure them explicitly. That way, the routes are part of your application design. With [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) APIs, you are usually designing APIs in a way that they represent “resources”. And then you are using HTTP verbs to indicate what you are actually doing. The included `ValuesController` is actually a good example for that:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet] Get()
// => Get all values

// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("{id}")] Get(int id)
// => Get a single value

// POST api/values
[HttpPost] Post([FromBody] string value)
// => Add a new value

// PUT api/values/5
[HttpPut("{id}")] Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
// => Set/replace a value

// DELETE api/values/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")] Delete(int id)
// => Delete a value
```

By not having any routing there by default, you don’t accidentally end up with method names within the route (since method names are usually imperative word combinations, making it more [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) instead of REST). Instead, you will have to deliberately expose your methods as actual routes with verbs.

In your exapmle, your `UserController` would probably be for a “User” resource. So registering a user would probably be a POST request to `/api/User`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not fully defined your route.

`[Route("api/[controller]")]` creates the `/api/User` portion of the url, but you have not specified the rest of the route on your action.

So your request should change from to `http://localhost:8011/api/User/RegisterUser` to `http://localhost:8011/api/User`